# In jquery how to put values of check-boxes which are ticked into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have check-boxes of "Apartment","House" etc.  I want to collect the values of these check-boxes into an array and send that array to controller using json. Since I'm new to jquery I don't know  how to put those values into an array using jquery ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = $("#hiddenroomdetails").val().split(",");
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) > -1) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
});
</script>






$.getJSON('@Url.Action("testcata", "home")' + '?property=' + selectedvalue +"&chkd="+checkedValues       
                       function (data) {

                      //code
                          })
```

Comment: You do not have to use jQuery to put this values into array. This can be done easily by pure JavaScript..

Comment: did you tried anything till now?

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov - Please let me know how to do that by giving an example

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar -  I'm trying to modify above query which is currently being used for getting the values in a hidden field separated by comma and check those check-boxes which have those values.

Comment: @SmokingMonkey This is very basic thing, so please surf the internet and learn how to create arrays and access DOM objects in JavaScript. Although if you would have some issues implementing it, I would be happy to help

Comment: Here is an example for you http://jsfiddle.net/mgzvm2s2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty common way to do it using jQuery is by using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method. For example:

```
var checkedValues = $('.check:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mgzvm2s2/

Comment: Nice code, much more clean than the answer I posted :)

Comment: Will the controller method receive this variable as an array ?

Comment: @Smokingmonkey It highly depends on how you send your data to controller. In ajax you can use something like this: `data: {cacked: checkedValues}` and see what values you get on server side .

Comment: @dfsq - see my updated ques. I am using json functinon to send array . when I check 1 check-box then its being received by the controller but when 2 values are there , controller is receiving null.

Comment: Try to use `$.getJSON('url', {property: selectedvalue, chkd: checkedValues })`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say if you give these checkboxes a class called "selectbox" and do the following code:

```
var selected = [];
$('.selectbox').click(function(){
    if(  $.inArray($(this).val(), selected) > -1 ){
        var index = selected.indexOf( $(this).val() );
        selected.splice( index, 1 );
    }
    else {
        selected.push( $(this).val() );
    }
}
```

This will fire an event when the checkboxes are clicked. It then checks if the value already exists in the "selected"-array. if it exists, it removes it (checkbox is unchecked). If it doesnt exist (checkbox is checked), it ads it.

Then you can pass on the "selected" array to the json function

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var Arr = [];
   $('.check:checked').map(function() {
      Arr.push(this.value);
   });
  alert(Arr);
  alert(Arr[0]);
})
```

[Check jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/0kvtudwt/)